# Having issue with UISplitViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, uisplitviewcontroller, unrecognized-selector

I have created a dictionary application and I am using `UISplitViewController` to search and select a word, my application crashes with this log :

`-[MeaningViewController topViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f918945bef0`

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MeaningViewController topViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f918945bef0'`

Here is my code :
in `ViewController (MasterView)` :

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender   {

    [_searchbar resignFirstResponder];

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Meaning"]) {

//MeaningViewController *meaningVC = (MeaningViewController*)[[segue destinationViewController] topViewController];

        UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        MeaningViewController *meaningVC = (MeaningViewController *)navController.topViewController;


        NSIndexPath*indexPath = _tableview.indexPathForSelectedRow;




        AppDelegate *appDelegateClass = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        Reader *selectedWord = [[appDelegateClass wordList] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        sqlite3 *database;
        NSString *mean = @"";

        if (sqlite3_open([appDelegateClass.currentDBPath cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

            NSString *sql =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT MEAN from DICM WHERE id = %ld",(long)selectedWord.oid];
            sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

            if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [sql UTF8String] , -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
                while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {


                    const char* f1 = (const char*)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 0);
                    mean = f1 == NULL ? nil : [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:f1];
                }}}


        readerClass = (Reader *)[appClass.wordList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        [meaningVC setGetWord:readerClass.Name];
        [meaningVC setGetMeaning:mean];
        [meaningVC setGetOid:readerClass.oid];

        dbClass=[[DB alloc]init];
        [dbClass setViewTime:readerClass.oid];

        NSLog(@"mean is %@",readerClass.Name);
    }
}
```

[image]

and in `MeaningViewController (Detail)` :

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {

        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        [_word setText:_getWord];
        [_mean setText:_getMean];
        oid = _getOid;
    }
```

The problem comes with this line :

UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        MeaningViewController *meaningVC = (MeaningViewController *)navController.topViewController;

If I replace above lines with this :

```
MeaningViewController *meaningVC = (MeaningViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
```

It works fine but it doesn't replace the detail view it just push view controller on `Master View` How can I fix this problem ?

here is `AppDelegate` codes :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    splitViewController.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayModeAllVisible;
    splitViewController.delegate = self;
return YES;

}


    - (BOOL)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)splitViewController collapseSecondaryViewController:(UIViewController *)secondaryViewController ontoPrimaryViewController:(UIViewController *)primaryViewController
    {

        return YES;
    }
```

Comment: The segue's destination controller is already your `MeaningViewController`, not a navigation controller.

Comment: @rmaddy What about this : `MeaningViewController *meaningVC = (MeaningViewController*)[[segue destinationViewController] topViewController];`  still crashes !

Comment: You want: `MeaningViewController *meaningVC = (MeaningViewController*)[segue destinationViewController] ;`

Comment: @rmaddy I did but this happens :
`http://i.imgur.com/8RH4frL.png`
The meaning view replaced with Master instead of Detail

Answer (score 0):

One problem that I can see is that your `DetailViewController` is not embedded in its own `UINavigationController`.  and your storyboard flow will be like:

```
->SplitVCont--UINavCont1--MasterVController--[O]--UINavCont2--DetailVController

->SplitVCont--UINavCont2--DetailViewController
```

[image: Storyboard]

with this,   in your `prepareForSegue` the segue.destinationViewController is guaranteed to be in all cases(collapse/split and in all devices) a kind of UINavigationController-class or you can  Introspection to be safe.

```
[segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]
```

-In some cases `DetailViewController` will be pushed to the `NavigationController` of `MasterViewController` (case iPhone 5 )

-In other cases `DetailViewController` will be in its own `NavigationController` and the `splitViewController` will handle all transitions of displayMode or DeviceOrientation using its default behaviour in your situation.

Comment: Thank you I just add another `Navigation Controller` for Detail View and it doesn't crash now but still have this problem :  `ttp://i.imgur.com/8RH4frL.png`

Comment: you welcome, try to tests using iPhone5 simulator see if you can see standard master-detail behaviour..if it does't work then its related to passing data to Detail and nothing to do with splitView

Comment: I see your image, so check your delegate :    if ([self.window.rootViewController isKindOfClass:[UISplitViewController class]]) {
        UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
        splitViewController.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayModeAllVisible;
        splitViewController.delegate = self;

    }

Comment: the delegate get set? i mean [self.window.rootViewController isKindOfClass:[UISplitViewController class]] is true

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113221/discussion-between-idali-and-mc-lover).